# In App Purchase: download extra data OR should information be contained in basic application

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing iPhone/iPad application with in-app-purchase. In-app-purchase requires extra data(~300KB .txt file).

1. Should data be downloaded after the purchase is done? I assume that it is necessary to set up my own server to retrieve the data(it can't be downloaded from some apple server for example)
2. OR should data be contained in basic application? Will apple approve this?

Comment: We can't answer "Will it be approved?". Only Apple knows if or not it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way is permissible as far as App Store approval is concerned. Use whichever works better for you.

(And yes, as of the current iOS release Apple will not host any extra data to be downloaded with an in-app purchase; you'll have to host it yourself.)